# How to process uploaded csv file by using web.py in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, web-applications, web.py

I am trying to make a API for my model.

I am trying to upload csv file and then read data in csv and then use model for prediction in API.

I am able to upload the file and save in path but unable to read csv data for prediction by using web.py in python

I have saved model for prediction and loaded in this code then predicting data.

upload.py

```
import web
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import requests

urls = ('/upload', 'Upload')

class Upload:

    def GET(self):

        web.header("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8")

        return """<html><head></head><body>
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                <input type="file" name="myfile" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" />
                </form>
                </body></html>"""    

    def POST(self):

        x = web.input(myfile=[])
        filedir = 'D:/API_CITY_PRED/Upload' # change this to the directory you want to store the file in.
        svmModel = open('D:/Model/model_city_id_predictor.pkl', 'rb')
        svmModel = joblib.load(svmModel)
        class_prediced = svmModel.predict(x)
        output = "Predicted City ID: " + str(class_prediced)
        print (output)

        if 'myfile' in x: # to check if the file-object is created
            filepath=x.myfile.filename.replace('\\','/') # replaces the windows-style slashes with linux ones.
            filename=filepath.split('/')[-1] # splits the and chooses the last part (the filename with extension)
            fout = open(filedir +'/'+ filename,'wb') # creates the file where the uploaded file should be stored
            fout.write(x.myfile.file.read()) # writes the uploaded file to the newly created file.
            fout.close() # closes the file, upload complete.

        return output
        raise web.seeother('/upload')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = web.application(urls, globals()) 
   app.run()
```

**Edit-1**

`# x is the input data`

`svmModel = open('D:/Model/model_city_id_predictor.pkl', 'rb') # SVM Model Imported 
svmModel = joblib.load(svmModel) # Model Loaded
class_prediced = svmModel.predict(x)  # here we are using to predict`

Please suggest

Comment: what's the error? Not knowing what is `model_city_id_predictor.pkl` makes this tough, but I'd be surprised if it knew what to do with `x`, a web.py <storage> object. Shouldn't you get the file from web.input, read it, and pass those results to `svmModel.predict(x)`?

Comment: Not getting any error, maybe some logical problem. We are taking input through `x` and `svmModel.predict(x)` using for prediction

Comment: But `predict()` doesn't understand `<web.utils.ThreadedDict>` type, it needs an array (or array of arrays?), so you'll need to read `x.myfile.file` and then pass the parsed results of that into `predict()`.

Comment: `x = web.input(myfile=[]) ` how to read csv through this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
x = web.input(file={})
fout = open('path/to/location/', 'wb')  # creates the file where the uploaded file should be stored
fout.write(x.file.file.read())  # writes the uploaded file to the newly created file.
fout.close()
```

This will write your file to the specified location.